# Changing text in a label not working in customtkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I am trying to create a simple age calculating program using customtkinter as it is my first time using it although for some reason the age is not showing up in the `age_label`. What is supposed to happen is you type in the year you were born in year_entry, press the `enter_button`, and then your age will show up next to `label_age` in `age_label` however nothing shows up in the `age_label`. I have tried setting the `age_label["text"]` to a string instead of a variable to see if it works but that doesn't work either.

```
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter
import tkinter.font as font

window = customtkinter.CTk()
window.geometry("300x100")
window.title("Age Calculator")
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)

def enterButton():
    year = year_entry.get()
    age = str(2022 - int(year))
    age_label["text"] = str(age)


customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("green")

label_year = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=window, text="Enter year of birth:", text_font=('Arial', 13))
label_year.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.2, anchor=tk.CENTER)

label_age = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=window, text="Age:", text_font=('Arial', 13))
label_age.place(relx=0.42, rely=0.7, anchor=tk.CENTER)

year_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=window, width=50, height=10, placeholder_text="Year")
year_entry.place(relx=0.65, rely=0.2, anchor=tk.E)

enter_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=window, text="Enter", width=80, height=7, corner_radius=5, command=enterButton)
enter_button.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.10)

age_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=window, text="", text_font=('Arial', 13), width=50)
age_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.55)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: When I replace all of the custom widgets with normal tkinter widgets,  your code works fine. Perhaps this is a bug with customtkinter.

Answer (score 2):

Changing attributes with the brackets notation like this:

```py
widget["attribute"] = new_value
```

is not implemented in CustomTkinter and won't be implemented in the future. I would also consider this bad coding style, because when you see the bracket notation with a string inside, you would assume it's a dictionary, but it's not.
You need to use the `.configure()` method:

```py
widget.configure(attribute=new_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the `.configure(text= new_string_value)` but I could not see it on the screen.

> Python 3.713
>
> customtkinter 5.0.3

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33572702)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

To solve it out, you can use tkinter object instead of CTkLabel:

In app mode :

```
self.Label_middle = tk.Label(self.home_frame, text ='Middle')
self.Label_middle.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor = 'center')
self.Label_middle.configure(text="2")
```

In your example:

```
Label_middle = tk.Label(master=window, text ='Middle')
Label_middle.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor = 'center')
Label_middle.configure(text="2")
```

It works perfectly :) (but then you have to set the font, background, ... )